# Listing of all elements recursively through postgresql

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, doctrine-orm

In my database I have basically a table (entity for `Doctrine`) called person and it looks like this:

```
class Person
{
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person")
     */
    private $parent;
}
```

I'd like to build a méthod `getAllChildren` which returns all persons under `person1` and recursively all persons under persons who have children.

**I'd like to know if I can do this through one recursive `SQL` request.**

> UPDATE1

postgres version: 9.1

```
  -- Table: person

  -- DROP TABLE person;

  CREATE TABLE person
  (
      id serial NOT NULL,
      parent_id integer,
      nom character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      prenom character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      age integer,
      description text,
      statut character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_7cbkzkd63HRzVK8e FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
      REFERENCES person(id) MATCH SIMPLE
  )
```

> UPDATE2

I've found http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/, this is pretty much what I need **except** my model is limitless

Comment: Yes, you can. But if you want a SQL answer, provide SQL details: table definition at the very least and preferably some sample data and PG version.

Comment: Your DDL is incomplete: `CONSTRAINT fk_7cbkzkd63HRzVK8e FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES person(id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to graciously deal with recursion at table level. For your specific question, the solution would be this (add the other columns from your table as needed; omitted here for brevity and focus):

```
WITH RECURSIVE p(parent, child, refs) AS (
  SELECT parent_id, id, 1 FROM person WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
UNION
  SELECT parent_id, child, refs+1 
  FROM person JOIN p ON id = parent)
SELECT * FROM p WHERE parent IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY parent, child;
```

The trick here is that you have to work your way **up** the hierarchy in order to find deeper levels of relationship; the `refs` column indicates the separation between `parent` and `child`. (Should you go **down** the hierarchy from any given `person.id` you can not link back up more than 1 level due to the way that the recursive CTE works, AFAIK. You probably can, but probably not as elegantly as in the above solution.)

I have found that it is oftentimes useful to include self-references, i.e. records where `parent = child` and `refs = 0`. The solution then becomes:

```
  WITH RECURSIVE p(parent, child, refs) AS (
    SELECT id, id, 0 FROM person WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL   -- the self-reference
  UNION
    SELECT parent_id, child, refs+1 
    FROM person JOIN p ON id = parent)
  SELECT * FROM p WHERE parent IS NOT NULL 
UNION
  SELECT id AS parent, id AS child, 0 AS refs   -- add the top-level node
  FROM person
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL
ORDER BY parent, child;
```

For ease of use, you can wrap the query in a view and then you simply create an entity of the view in Doctrine to get at the data.